# Old Data not being overridden by new user input in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component that is performing a series of conditionals to check if there is previous data when editing a form. Since the form is being edited there is always previous data but if I type something into the input field and click the save button, my newly typed input is not being persisted but rather the same old data is remaining. I understand that it is happening because the `v-if` condition is always true but I cannot think of a way to modify the condition if the user types new data in to replace it. The original job is being passed in as a prop which contains the old/original data.

A conditional from my vue:

```html
<div v-if="job.title">
  <input :value="job.title" id="title" name="title" type="text" required>
</div>
<div v-else>
  <input v-model="newJob.title" id="title" name="title" type="text" required>
</div>
```

```js
props: {
  route: String,
  job: Object,
},
data() {
  return {
    newJob: {
      title: ''
    },
  }
},
```

So when I type new information the `v-model` for the `newJob` is not being updated in the vue dev tools. How do I get the newJob field to update IF the user types something in, otherwise continue to save the old/original value that was in the edit form when the page loaded.

Comment: @phil sorry about the formatting.

Comment: If `job.title` exists then the first input is shown and you are not using `v-model` or `@input` to handle changes, so nothing will change, right?

Comment: @DecadeMoon that is correct. So what I want is if a user starts typing something or replaces the original value then the new value is recognized by vue and that new value is persisted to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need

```
<input v-model="newJob.title" id="title" name="title" type="text" required>
```

and

```
props: {
    job: Object,
},
data() {
    return {
        newJob: {
            title: this.job.title || "",
        },
    };
},
```

Comment: this worked. It was obvious after the fact. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use a property with an object as its default value rather than a prop and a data value:

```
<input :value="job.title" id="title" name="title" type="text" required>
```

and

```
job: {
  type: Object,
  default: function () {
    return {
          title: '',
     }
  }
},
```